# Sort numeric field used in hierarchy

Tags: sorting, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a hierarchy that is Year-Month-Day, and it sorts the day as if it were a text field (i.e, 1,10,11,12,etc). When the same fields are used without the hierarchy the sort is correct. The model is SSAS 2012 tabular, and the field is properly set up as a Whole Number data type/format.

I can't think of, or find anything else to change this behaviour - there's no properties on the hierarchy for setting a sort field, and nothing else that I can find that changes this.

Does anyone know how to get a numeric field to sort properly in a hierarchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been resolved by shutting down both Visual Studio and Excel and re-starting them.